# What is Edge to Edge Routing?

Tags: networking, routing

I've heard the term edge to edge routing several times, but I'm having a hard time finding a formal definition as to what exactly this means. Can someone please explain what edge to edge routing is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like most IT terms, there is no formal definition. It means whatever the vendor wants it to mean.

But edge-to-edge routing in a cloud provider context means essentially using a "virtual cloud"** as a transit between another cloud and some other network (*i.e.*, routing from one edge of the cloud to another).

For example, you have a corporate network connected to one Amazon VPC (A).   That VPC is also connected to another VPC (B).  Routing from your corporate network through VPC A to reach VPC B is an example of edge to edge routing (and it's not allowed).

Here is an [Amazon document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/invalid-peering-configurations.html#edge-to-edge-vgw) that uses the term extensively.

** Cloud providers have different product names for this:  Virtual Private Cloud or Virtual Network.

Comment: Not allowed by Amazon or not allowed in some other way?

Comment: Amazon doesn’t allow VPCs to be transitive. So they don’t allow it. But if you use your own routers, you can make it happen.